# Figure is not shown in DVI

Tags: dvi, dvi-mode

This is a sample .tex file

```
\documentclass[dvipdfm]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[bb = 0 0 1937 1912]{test.jpg}}
\caption{This is a test figure.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I compile the above .tex file and the compilation is free or warning and errors. However when I open the .dvi the figure is not shown, while the caption is written. Only when I compile the dvi to pdf the figure is visible. So, my question: Is there a way to make the figure visible in both modes (DVI and PDF)?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is almost always better, and never worse, to use `\includegraphics[bb = 0 0 1937 1912, width=\hsize]{test.jpg}` rather than `\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics[bb = 0 0 1937 1912]{test.jpg}}`

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard for the inclusion of images in the DVI file. The DVI file format does not know anything about figures. Thus the image support is done via `\special{...}`. The syntax of the contents for `\special` depends on the DVI driver. The file in the question uses driver option `dvipdfm`, thus the `graphics` package writes the `\special` for `dvipdfm`. Since `dvipdfm` only converts DVI to PDF and cannot view anything, you have to use a different DVI viewer, which apparently does not support specials for `dvipdfm`. If you want to have the images included in the DVI viewer, you have to compile again with a different driver option to get specials for the DVI viewer with some hope, that the viewer also supports the used image format.

Comment: If I use `\documentclass{article}` without the [dvipdfm] option then the figure is shown in the .dvi output but then when I compile to .pdf the size of the same figure is very small confined at the lower left part of the bounding box. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Without option, `dvips` is usually used as default and the DVI viewer recognizes the special. But for `dvipdfm`, you have to recompile with driver option `dvipdfm`.